# Amazon CloudFront distribution is configured to block access from your country

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I keep getting this when I try to visit a website that I have previously visited many times before.

> 403 ERROR
>
> The request could not be satisfied.
>
> The Amazon CloudFront distribution is configured to block access from your country. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
>
> If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
>
> Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
>
> Request ID: db4AJqwG88H12zSDESOE7SIS8twSWZGScHR005VdWdEQ4RF8fx_ITA==

Answer (score 4):

This **might** mean that the website is blocked on your country, your IP is blocked, or the website it's wrongly configured.

You can try contacting the site owner.

Comment: Thank you so much, Sebastian! I appreciate it very kindly.

Comment: No problem , consider marking question as solution.